# Systemd enabled services not starting on boot up but able to start manually

Tags: systemd

I have created below test.service at /etc/systemd/system/

```
[Unit]
Description=Operations
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/sga/tools/test_service_start.sh

ExecStop=/opt/sga/tools/test_stop.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

If I do systemctl -l status test.service below is the command output:

```
● test.service - test_Operations
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

If I do "journalctl -u test.service -b" after a reboot:

```
 - No entries
```

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

When working with the system bus, we usually use:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Depending on your system `default.target` is probably aliased (symlinked) to `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`.  On my system, I can see that default.target is symlinked to `graphical.target`:

```
$ systemctl status default.target
● graphical.target - Graphical Interface
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; static)
     Active: active since Wed 2021-03-17 07:44:06 CET; 6h ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

`graphical.target` is a little strange because if you need a graphical environment to run your stuff, you should usually be using the user-bus instead of the system bus.  Otherwise you get problems if you don't also set `XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY`

I see two options for you:

1. Use `WantedBy=multi-user.target` if your application doesn't need a graphical environment.  Before editing the filem, run `sudo systemctl disable test.service` to delete the symlink, then edit the file and run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable test.service`.
2. Keep `WantedBy=default.target`, but move your service to the user bus if you need the graphical environment. Another option on the user bus is `graphical-session.target`.  However it isn't implemented by DEs as well as it should be yet, so while that sounds like a better match, check if it is raised on your system before choosing that instead.